# Module not found while importing nested module

Tags: node.js, typescript, lerna

Suppose that we have `package1` and `package2`. If `package2` tries to import `package1` module we get an error that says `module not found`. Import looks like `import { ... } from 'package1/styles'`. Keep in mind that imports like `import { ... } from 'package1'` works. In my opinion these import issues are caused because lerna incorrectly links folders. I would expect that `node_modules` of `package2` should contain only `package1/dist` instead of `package1`. How these import issues should be solved?

Relevant `package1` files below.

```
package.json:

...
"main": "./dist/index.js",
"files": ["dist"]
...
```

```
tsconfig.json:

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

After we run `lerna run build` we get following directory structure:

```
packages/package2/node_modules/package1/
├── dist
│  ├── index.d.ts
│  ├── index.js
│  └── styles
│     ├── index.d.ts
│     └── index.js
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│  ├── index.ts
│  └── styles
│     └── index.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tsconfig.json` should have paths that would resolve module dependencies like:

```
...
    "baseUrl": "./packages",
    "paths": {
      "package1": ["./package1/src"],
      "package1/*": ["./package1/src/*"]
    }
...
```